# How to Change Pentaho Repository

Tags: sql-server, pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration, spoon

I'm using Pentaho Spoon to Data iteration now, and I want to Change Repository Database of Pentaho.

As I know Pentaho repository server is HsqlDB, and I want to change HsqlDB to MSSQL

So I searched about this, and I followed page 'https://help.hitachivantara.com/Documentation/Pentaho/8.0/Setup/Installation/Archive/Start_Pentaho_Server' , but it didn't work out.

Is there any way to change repository of Pentaho?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you install `archive` version of Pentaho Server from your link so you can follow the steps to config MS SQL Server as a repository database from [here](https://help.hitachivantara.com/Documentation/Pentaho/9.4/Setup/Use_MS_SQL_Server_as_your_repository_database_(Archive_installation)) but if you install `manual` version of Pentaho Server you can follow from [here](https://help.hitachivantara.com/Documentation/Pentaho/9.4/Setup/Use_MS_SQL_Server_as_your_repository_database_(Manual_installation))